# Returning account name using account from an ArrayList that saved in a Text File

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

Return account name using accountno in an arraylist?
I'm having trouble in returning the account name when searching the accountno.
I just want when the user enter the account no in account field, the account name associated with that account no will display in account name field.

```
private void txt_wdaccountnumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
for(BankAccount account: list){
    if(account.getAccountNo().equals(txt_wdaccountnumber.getText())){
    txt_wdaccountname.setText(account.getAccountName());
        System.out.println(txt_wdaccountname);
        return;
```

Adding an Account:

```
private void btnSaveAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(rad_savings);
    bg.add(rad_checking);
    account.setAccountName(txt_accountname.getText());
    account.setAccountNo(txt_accountnumber.getText());
    account.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(txt_initialbalance.getText()));
    list.add(account);
    String fileName = "bank.txt";
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (BankAccount str : list) {
            pw.println(str);
           }

        pw.flush();
        pw.println("\n");
```

Comment: How in the world will we know what all these "account" related objects are, if you don't clarify this?

Comment: Sorry, "account" is `BankAccount account = new BankAccount();` arraylist name.

Comment: Don't print out the txt_wdaccountname since that is a JTextField. Print out the String returned by `getAccountName()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the if condition is true, then you have the BankAccount of interest held by the account variable -- and so you then use it:

```
for(BankAccount account: list){
  if(account.getAccountNo().equals(txt_wdaccountnumber.getText())){

    // the account variable will now hold the BankAccount of interest

    // let's test to see if we are getting to this spot

    String accountName = account.getName();
    System.out.println("inside if block. accountName: " + accountName);

    txt_wdaccountname.setText(accountName);
    return;
  }
}
```

Note that I'm not sure what you call your JTextField that displays the account's name, or the method of BankAccount to get that name, so I guessed in the code above, but you should get the idea and go from there.

Comment: `txt_wdaccountname` is the name of the jtextfield for the account name. I've tried your solution, but it return nothing.

Comment: @dyonas: please edit your original question and add to the bottom of it the new code that you've tried. Also, consider putting in `System.out.println(...)` inside that if block to see if it's even being called. For example, see my edited answer.

Comment: @dyonas have u ever call the acount.setName("something") to populate that object to have any result, try to debug it first

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - still no result. This accounts were saved in an arraylist and also write in a file. Should i declare the filename to get the account no, account name, balance?

Comment: @dyonas: I've no idea as there are too many unknowns that only you know, but we don't. For all we know your account number is an int or Integer, or the JButton hasn't had an ActionListener added to it. YOu will need to do a lot of debugging to try to isolate the error.